# When load the electron renderer，What is the different about the require between http:// and file://?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, require, renderer

I run an electron app by running `electron ./dist/main.js`

In the electron `renderer-process`, I load a webpage and run `require('lodash')` in the webpage.

When I load the webpage by `http://`, I can't get the `lodash` module,
but when I use `file://`, I get it.

So I want to know what the different about `require()` between `http` and `file` in electron `renderer-process`.

Answer (score 1):

`file://` means you are fetching file from your own computer and `http://` is used for requesting file from the `server`.